# Have an option to run an exe file on a specific file suffix

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu, regedit

I want to have an option to run an EXE (or .py) file on the context menu when I right click a file (for example .mp4) for example like what Notepad++ does, you right click a file and it has the option to "Edit with Notepad++", so I want it to say "test" when I click a .mp3 file.

I did try to search it up but I don't really know what to search... I think it's possible with Regedit but I still don't know how to use it correctly.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the contents of a .reg file you can safely merge, study, & modify. Since you want a command to be associated with the `.mp3` extension, *regarless of the default Application association*, you want to create it under `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3\Shell\MyCommand]
@="NewMenuVerb"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp3\Shell\MyCommand\Command]
@="Notepad \"%1\""
```

In the command line, `Notepad "%1"`, the `%1` will receive the fully-qualified path of the selected file. It surrounded by quotes in case there are spaces in the path name. Note the difference between the registry file syntax & what is merged tot he regisry. In the example, **Notepad** doesn't require an actual path to hte executable because it's a registered applicaiton. You may need a literal or expandable path to your executable. Browse through the registry examining the Command subkeys for examples.